# Radix sorting code confusion

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, sorting

I have a question about this algo:

[image]

(Slide taken [from here.](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/18RadixSort.pdf))

```
int N = a.length;
int[] count = new int[R];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
 count[a[i]+1]++;
for (int k = 1; k < 256; k++)
 count[k] += count[k-1];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
 temp[count[a[i]++]] = a[i]
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
 a[i] = temp[i];
```

Can someone elaborate about the 3rd for loop where we move the records from a[] to temp[]?

I know after we accumulate counts they're supposed to be some sort of offset. So we can insert the letters in proper place in temp[].

**I'm just not sure what the a[i]++ is doing in there.** (<-main question) I know where referencing the letter in the count array, but why do we increment the letter too? Did we change letters? Thanks.

Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like a typo:
it should be:

```
temp[count[a[i]]++]
```

the next element should go into the next empty space

in step1 prepares for adds `type_i` counts to `cnt_{i+1}`, this way making space for `type_i` elements...

step2 is a prefix on the counts

step3 uses counts as `R` index pointers and sends all elements from `a` to its final destination

invariant holded at this step:

- `count[ x ]` points to the next empty space where an `type_x` element can be placed (or there are no more `x` elements in the input)

Comment: Since when we made counts[a[i]+1]++ on the first for loop, we increment the type_i+1's frequency right?

On the slide it should be a=0, b=2, c=5... right?

Comment: i think the original slides were animated...and played the whole algorithm...but in this pdf only the final state is shown